# Counterexample with mapping

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $f$ is mapping from metric space $X$ into metric space $Y$. Let $E$ some subset of $X$. Am I true if $f(x)\in f(E)$ then doesn't imply that $x\in E$?

Let $f(x)=x^2$ and $X=Y=\mathbb{R}^1.$ Taking $E=[0,1]$ then $f(E)=[0,1]$ but $f(-\frac{1}{2})\in [0,1]$ and $-\frac{1}{2}\notin E$. Am I true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. An even easier example is $f: \mathbb R\to \{0\}$ (which must be constant). Then $f([0,1]) = \{0\}$ and $f(-1/2) \in \{0\}$ but $-1/2\not\in[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Every function $f : X \to Y$ which fails to be one-to-one gives a counterexample: if $x \ne y$ and $f(x)=f(y)$ simply take $E=\{y\}$.

Comment: Great! It's really interesting fact.